# ¿Es posible instalar una versión que ya no existe de un paquete npm?

Tags: ionic, npm, github, plugin, control-de-versiones

Tengo un proyecto en Ionic y necesito de la instalación de un plugin en su versión 2.

El plugin anteriormente permanecía a un paquete npm con versiones que iban desde 1.0.0 hasta 3.0.3, actualmente el plugin se mudo de paquete y solo contiene una única versión, versión 3.0.3.
Ambos paquetes (tanto el antiguo como el nuevo) apuntan a una misma dirección GitHub que contiene el mismo proyecto y en el cual si están todas las versiones antiguas.

¿Es posible conseguir esas versiones antiguas de GitHub mediante el nuevo paquete npm?

Antiguo paquete npm del plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

Nuevo paquete npm del plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Comment: Por lo que veo [aqui](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/branches) existe un branch con la versión 2. Pero te recomendaría (sin conocer este plugin todo sea dicho) que si puedes actualices a la última versión, nunca esta de más y es mas fácil hacerlo de versión a versión que si posteriormente sale alguna que te puede interesar más.

Comment: Hola @ElGerar, no me ah sido posible o desconozco de la manera mediante npm de acceder a ese branch... Por otro lado eh intentado actualizarme a la ultima versión pero eh tenido unos problemas de integración que en mi opinión es causado por versión 3.0.3 BETA (problema de integración: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258970/backgroundgeolocationplugin-only-refers-to-a-type-but-is-being-used-a-value-h)

Answer (score 0):

Sí es posible! después del nombre del paquete debes agregarle el arroba "@".
Ahora...
Supongamos que:

A--> querés instalar opencv y conoces exactamente la versión que queres instalar.. entonces:

`npm install opencv@4.17.4`

B-->querés instalar opencv pero NO conoces exactamente la versión que queres instalar.. entonces al arroba le sumas el Acento circunflejo " ^ " :

`npm install opencv@^4.0.0`

Eso va a instalar la ultima version 4.x.x
Para mas info podes ir a: https://docs.npmjs.com

Comment: Hola @NicoCarosio! Si, estaba informado de esa bandera en el comando... Pero en este caso en particular no funciona ya que el plugin se cambio de paquete npm y el paquete nuevo no brinda esas versiones a pesar de que estén en GitHub, mira aquí están las versiones del paquete anterior que ya esta obsoleto https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation?activeTab=versions y aquí las versiones que se pueden alcanzar con npm en el nuevo paquete https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/v/3.0.3?activeTab=versions