# 'BackgroundGeolocationPlugin' only refers to a type, but is being used a value here

Tags: angular, ionic, plugin

Tengo una aplicación en ionic y quiero integrar un plugin de geocalizacion de fondo mediante npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation).

Antes usaba la versión 2 del plugin la cual me dejaba importar el plugin en NgModule sin problemas, esa version no se me ah sido posible instalarla por el siguiente problema: [¿Es posible instalar una versión que ya no existe de un paquete npm?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258963/es-posible-instalar-una-versi%C3%B3n-que-ya-no-existe-de-un-paquete-npm)

Ahora al momento de usar la versión actual del nuevo paquete, versión 3.0.3, tengo el siguiente problema para declarar el plugin en ngModule:

[image: Interface, no class]
El plugin me deja importar una interface no una class como habitualmente acostumbraba.

[image: Error al agregar la declaración del plugin]

Por lo cual me da el error `'BackgroundGeolocationPlugin' only refers to a type, but is being used a value here.` al intentar declarar el plugin.

Comment: En provide no esta permitido anadir interfaces. Estas seguro que el import que haces es el correcto?

Comment: Hola! No se que este realizando mal, pero es un plugin como cualquier otro. Lo instalo como cualquier otro, pero a la hora de agregar la dependencia en `NgModule` solo me proporciona interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucha investigación, descubrí que mi error estaba en la instalación del plugin, existía un paquete dentro de ámbito de integración (`@ionic-native`) del paquete original con Ionic en el que se acoplaba de forma correcta el plugin `@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation`.

```
  ionic cordova plugin add @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation
  npm install @ionic-native/background-geolocation@3.1.0-rc.1
```

A pesar de esto no recomiendo la utilización de este plugin, considero que no funciona de forma adecuada y a su vez provoca problemas con otros plugins instalados.